A maximally distant unitary from a parameterized circuit
I have a parameterized circuit that includes a certain number of rotation gates, each parameterized by an angle. By sampling over these angles, I can obtain various unitaries. What are the unitaries that I cannot reach? And among those, which ones are the farthest (by some suitable norm like fidelity) from their best approximations achievable with the parameterized circuit?

Please clarify (1) what kind of circuits you are building and (2) what value you assign to the parameters. I believe this information is necessary to get a proper answer.

@Daniele Cuomo It is one of the circuits considered here -  Expressibility and entangling capability of parameterized quantum circuits for hybrid quantum-classical algorithms. F.e., Circuit 2, Figure 2 in there. The circuits includes $2n\ell$ rotations, where $n$ is the number of qubits and $\ell$ is the number of concatenated blocks. Therefore, the circuit is parameterized with $2n\ell$  angles (let's say, each one $\in [-\pi,\pi]$).
